# Safari: table-layout: fixed in absolutely positioned element doesn't stretch parent

Tags: html, safari, fixed, tablelayout

I have a `div` with `display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%` as a child of another `div` with `position: absolute`. On Chrome, IE, and Firefox, the child div with `table-layout: fixed` makes the parent `div` expand to `100%`, but in Safari (6.0.4, OS X 10.8.3) this doesn't happen. Here's a picture

[image: Safari rendering problem]

and a jsbin http://jsbin.com/oqupah/6/edit (make sure to open the output in a new window). The markup is something like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;border: 1px solid black">
  <div style="display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%;border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid green">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is with the HTML 5 and XHTML 1.0 doctypes. I noticed that if I remove the doctype in safari, it will behave like the other browsers, but removing the doctype is not an option.

In practice, I had this code when I was implementing an absolutely positioned popup, where the content of the popup is a `div` with `display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%`. I want the popup to stretch 100% so that I can easily provide a `max-width` and that if the window was resized, the popup would shrink accordingly.

So I'm guessing this is a bug in Safari? The behavior on mobile safari is the same. Is there something I can add to make it behave like the other browsers?

Comment: Works good on Safari 5.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix is to add `right: 0` to the absolutely positioned `div`

... wasted so much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this on the `display:table` element :

```
table-layout: fixed;
max-width: none;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
```